# Соотношение padding, margin, border текущего элемента и width-а родительского элемента

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, margin, padding

Хочу сверстать адаптивный, резиновый сайт. Возник вопрос: нужно задавать padding-и, margin-ы, border-ы текущего элемента в %  относительно текущего div-а или родительского div-а (желателен пример)?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        all__buttons=document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
        
            [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button){
                selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    event.target.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
                    event.target.style.color='#ffffff';
                
                });
            }); 
        */
    
        $('.header__button').click(function(event){
                $('.header__button').removeClass('lilac');
                $(this).addClass('lilac');
                event.target.style.color='#ffffff';
        }
        );

const getItem = `<div class="cardexample">
                            <div class="mobileimage">
                                    <img class="mobiles" src="../img/mobileimage.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content__title">
                                Iphone 11, почему такой же как и Pro Max, может быть большим в 3 строки вот так
                            </div>
                            <div class="video__icon">
                                <span>
                                    <button class="crashvideo">Краш видео</button>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <a href="#"><img class="youtube__icon-play" src="../img/Vector.png"></a>
                                </span> 
                                <span>
                                    <button class="crashvideo" id="ex2">Краш видео</button>
                                </span>                         
                            </div>
                            <div class="content__text">
                                Видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые вопросы может быть большим в 3 строки, видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые
                            </div>
                            <div class="endlink">
                                <a href="#">Читать далее</a>
                            </div>              
                        </div>
                        `;  



        if  (document.documentElement.clientWidth<640)
        {
            
            const getAllItems = () => {
                let content = '';
                
                for (let i=0; i<4; i++) {
                    content+=getItem;
                }
                return content;
            }       

            const renderAllItems = () => {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=getAllItems();
            }

            renderAllItems();
            console.log('Mobile');
            
        }
        
        
        if ((window.innerWidth>=640) && (window.innerWidth<=1023))
        {
            /*document.getElementsByClassName('content__article').innerHTML = getItem;*/
            /*document.querySelectorAll('.content__article').forEach(i => i.innerHTML = getItem);*/
            let blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.content__article');
            
            for (let block of blocks)
            {
                block.innerHTML=getItem;
                /*document.querySelectorAll('.content__article')[i].innerHTML = getItem;*/
            }
            
            console.log('Tablet');
            
        
        }
        
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1023)
        {
            console.log('Desktop');
        }
    
    }
    
    
    )
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: (calc(93/360))%;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #5f3ec0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px (calc(15/360))% 7px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="globalcontainer">
                <div class="header">
                        <div class="header__text">
                            Обзоры
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__buttons">
                            <!-- <span> -->
                                <button class="header__button">Все</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Видео</button>               
                                <button class="header__button">Текст</button>               
                                <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
                            <!-- </span> -->
                        </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="content" id="content">
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__article">
                        
                        </div>
                </div>              
                </div>              
                <button class="show__more">Показать еще</button>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <div class="footer">
                <div class="threecolumnfooter">
                        <div class="firstfootercolumn">
                                <div class="logo__company">
                                    <img src="../img/lastlogo1.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="contacts">
                                    <div class="contacts__title">
                                        Контакты
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="contacts__telephones">
                                        <div class="telephone1">
                                        +7 (800) 333 32 24
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="telephone2">
                                        +7 (812) 448 68 11
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="requestcall">
                                        Заказать звонок
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="privacy__policy">
                                    Политика конфиденциальности
                                </div>
                                <div class="terms__of__use">
                                    Пользовательское соглашение
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="secondfootercolumn">
                                <div class="internetshop">
                                        <div class="internetshop__title">
                                            Интернет магазин
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="disclosure__arrow">
                                            >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="about__shop">
                                            О магазине
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="delivery__and__payment">
                                            Доставка и оплата
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="guarantees__and__returns">
                                            Гарантии и возврат
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="credit__and__installments">
                                            Кредит и рассрочка
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trade__in">
                                            Trade-in
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="promotions">
                                            Акции
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="catalog">
                                            Каталог товаров
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="service">
                                            Сервис
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="news">
                                            Новости
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="reviews">
                                            Обзоры
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thirdfootercolumn">
                                <div class="company">
                                        <div class="company__title">
                                            Компания
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="disclosure__arrow">
                                            >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="about__us">
                                            О нас
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="company__news">
                                            Новости
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vacancies">
                                            Вакансии
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="company__contacts">
                                            Контакты
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="help__to__the__buyer">
                                        <div class="help__to__the__buyer__title">
                                            Помощь покупателю
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="help__to__the__buyer__title__for__tablet">
                                            Помощь
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="disclosure__arrow">
                                            >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contacts__for__help">
                                            Контакты
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="warranty__and__return">
                                            Гарантия и возврат
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="service__for__help">
                                            Сервис
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="support">
                                            Поддержка
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footerend">
                <div class="socialnetworks__links">
                        <div class="socialnetworks__links__title">
                            Мы в соц. сетях
                        </div>
                        <div class="socialnetworks__links-images">
                            <div class="facebook-image">
                                <embed src="../img/facebook.svg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="allrights">
                        <div class="allrights__text">
                            © 2020 Все права защищены
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как задать размеры элемента header__text, header__buttons и header__button, и относительно каких элементов, чтобы было резиново? Какой элемент является родительским по отношению к margin-right, указанному на рисунке (см. @Paprika)? Паддинги и бордеры должны задаваться относительно div-а, который они обрамляют, а мэрджины относительно div-a, в котором они содержатся? (правильно ли я понял @Paprika)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я может чего-то не понимаю из вашего вопроса, но как можно задать padding в % относительно текущего элемента? Ведь "При указании поля в процентах, значение считается от ширины **родителя** элемента." https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7kov0s/
Если "желателен пример" это вопрос к сообществу - да, желательно бы увидеть от вас пример, чтобы лучше понимать суть вопроса)

Comment: @Paprika об элементах .header__text, .header__button и .header__button - как задать размеры в %, чтобы сайт был резиновым?

Comment: ничего не понятно. менять пэдинги и мэрджины относительно размера чего? а главное зачем? при чем тут резиновость к margin и padding. Задайте значения в процентах от ширини экрана `margin: .1vw` но главное зачем, если относительно менять размер то относительно ширины или высоты, и величины какого элемента (если дива то див как меняет размер относительно ширины или высоты экрана)?

Comment: `if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1023)` а почему не [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) как js поможет нам разобратся в вашей проблеме? Прочитайте пожалуйста [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) добавляя столько текста, скриптов и DOM элементов в пример вы хотите запутать нас или думаете что проблема где то в js или в DOM дереве?

Comment: `(calc(15/360))` calc не так считает, он может посчитать когда будет значть величины `calc(15% / 5)`, `calc(200px / 4)`, `calc(100% - 30px)`. Не понятно что за величина 15 и 360 это проценты, пиксели, градусы? если константы то лучше вывести в css variables `:root{--somevariable: 15px}`

Comment: Какая формула должна быть? 15/360 - это при ширине 360 px padding должен быть 15px а при увеличении/уменьшии - менятся пропорционально ширине экрана?

Comment: @Greg-- marginwidth/windowwidth , marginwidth: 15px, windowwidth: 360px

Comment: `marginwidth` нет такой величины но если я правильно понял `padding: 7px calc(0.042 * 100vw) 7px 0px;` - по такой формуле отношение пэдинга к ширине экрана будет всегда одинаково